# RPG timestamp validation, is this best practice?

Tags: timestamp, rpgle

For RPG timestamp validation, is this best practice?  It seem that there should be a way to test using TEST opcode?

```
d DateTimeST      S               Z                                          
d Value           S             26A                                          
d*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
c                   Eval      Value = '2017-11-16-09.54.40.840586'           
c                   Eval      DateTimeST = %timestamp(Value)                 
c                   If        %Error                                         
c                   EXSR      DoSometing                                     
c                   ENDIF                                                    
c*-------------------------------------------------------------------        
c     DoSometing    BEGSR                                                    
c                   ENDSR                                                    
c*-------------------------------------------------------------------        
c                   Eval         *inlr = *on                                 
c                   return
```

Answer (score 2):

Best practice these days looks more like this:

```
**free
dcl-s DateTimeSt       Timestamp;
dcl-s Value            Char(26);

Value = '2017-11-16-09.54.40.840586';
test(ze) Value;
if %error;
   DoSomething();
else;
   DateTimeSt = %timestamp(value);
endif;
return;

// Error Proc
dcl-proc DoSomething;
end-proc;
```

The problem I have with `MONITOR` groups is that they litter your job log with error messages, even if you handle the error, so you need extra code to remove the message from the job log.

Answer (score 1):

Mustapha,

You can test a timestamp using the TEST(ZE) opcode. The Z extender specifies you're testing a timestamp and the E extender sets the %Error on if the test fails.

As Mike mentioned, you can also wrap it in a monitor group and use the On-Error opcode to run your subroutine.

Sample code for both methods is below.

```
 d DateTimeST      S               Z
 d Value           S             26A
 d*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 c                   Eval      Value = '2017-11-16-09.54.40.840586'
 c
 c* Method #1 - use monitor group
 c                   Monitor
 c                   Eval      DateTimeST = %timestamp(Value:*ISO)
 c                   On-Error
 c                   EXSR      DoSometing
 c                   Endmon
 c
 c* Method #2 - use Test(ZE)
 c     *ISO          Test(ZE)                Value
 c                   If        %Error
 c                   EXSR      DoSometing
 c                   Else
 c                   Eval      DateTimeST = %timestamp(Value:*ISO)
 c                   Endif
 c
 c                   Eval         *inlr = *on
 c                   return
 c*-------------------------------------------------------------------
 c     DoSometing    BEGSR
 c                   ENDSR
 c*-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an RNX0112 error at runtime. Use Monitor/On-Error *All/EndMon